# Using excel/vba to generate solutions to a multi

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel to generate numbers from a basic formula that has 2 variables. I have 600 numbers (specifically coordinates), that I need to generate 13 new numbers from each (so I'll need a total of 8400 values/rows for each X & Y). Since the formula will need to change every 14 rows to a new absolute cell, I am having a hard time thinking of how to accomplish this in Excel using VBA.

My current thought is this:

1. Add rows to accommodate for the new values.
2. Fill down columns C and D with the repeating pattern of values.
3. Create a loop that runs the formula for 14 rows then repeats, keeping the absolute value based on position (?).

Admittedly, I am not a pro at VBA, so any help on how to accomplish this task is greatly appreciated.

See screen grab of data, below, for an example.

[Snippet of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RABVS.jpg)

I used this code to get 13 new rows for my values.

```
Sub AddRows()
  ScreenUpdating = False
  With ActiveSheet
    lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
  End With
  Dim AddRows As Integer: AddRows = 13
  Dim i As Integer: i = lastRow
  Do While i <> 1
    Rows(i & ":" & i + AddRows - 1).Insert
    i = i - 1
  Loop
  ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: you could use OFFSET.  this can be done in or out of VBA.  Set up your formula and then put in the OFFSET function for your cell references.  As your 14 row counter you could do something like  INT(counter/14).  Without VBA I would be using row() or row()-Row ($A$1) as my counter.